# Dropdown Menu não funciona

Tags: html, css

Estou criando um header contendo um dropdown menu, mas preciso que quando a pessoa clique em produtos abra um outro dropdown com mais informações, quando eu clico não aparece.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button
            class="navbar-toggle"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-collapse"
          >
            <span class="icon icon-bar" />
            <span class="icon icon-bar" />
            <span class="icon icon-bar" />
          </button>
          <img
            class="img-fluid"
           
            src="image/logo.jpg"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ">
            <li class="active">
              <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Acesso Rápido
                <span class="caret" />
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Portal</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">
                    TopDesk
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Portal 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Nossas Politicas</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Nossos Negocios
                <span class="caret" />
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Empresa</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#Custom"
                  >
                    Custom
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#Connect"
                  >
                    Connect
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#Protect"
                  >
                    Protect
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#Experience"
                  >
                    Experience
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a
                href="#"
                class="dropdown-toggle"
                data-toggle="dropdown"
                role="button"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                Institucional
                <span class="caret" />
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">People</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#">Serviços</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    class="dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                    role="button"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    Products<span class="caret" />
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li class="active">
                      <a href="#">teste</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">teste2</a>
                    </li>
                    
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Onde tem escrito "produtos"?

Comment: Bom, como a pergunta não explica muita coisa, me pareceu ser uma duplicada. Se puder edita-la com mais informações ela poderá ser reaberta, ou a outra marcada como duplicada pode ter a solução do seu problema.